# SpringWebFlux doOnError handling

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

In our project we have some kind of fallback in case of something bad happened and is treated by **doOnError**. My only concern is that maybe **doOnError** operator is not used in a correct way. So let's take a look on the next example:

```
callService1()
.flatMap(service1Response -> {
  //process service1Response
})
.doOnError(callService2.subscribe())
```

When the flow arrives in doOnError, we're calling another service.

In doOnError we have to **subscribe** manually to the Mono retrieved by the **callService2** in order for the code to be executed, and beside that if an error is thrown in doOnError, that error is not catched by our GlobalErrorHandler.

Should we rethink our error handling in this case ? I'd really want to not subscribe manually to a publisher. What do you think ? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `onErrorResume` operator to return another Mono if error happen. See [reactor operator guide](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#which.errors) for other relevant operator.

```
callService1()
.flatMap(service1Response -> {
  //process service1Response
})
.onErrorResume(err -> callService2())
```